# Jquery Filter next select group based on selection of previous select group

Tags: jquery

So I need a user to select three select boxes (all multiselect).

The idea is that there are many different specific types of desserts, and instead of having one huge multi-select box, I include two other multi-select boxes to narrow down what the user has to click.

In this case, they first go through the "layer1", click on Cookie, and then the second layer should only show Sprinkled Cookie and Iced Cookie.

Then, on the "layer2" if they select both Sprinkled Cookie and Iced Cookie, then  Dark Sprinkled Cookie and White Sprinkled Cookie, and White Iced Cookie should show up on "layer3".

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the filter and replacing the html text with the right result.

```
<select id="layer1" multiple="multiple">
  <option my_id=3>Chocolate</option>
  <option my_id=5>Cookie</option>
</select>

<select id="layer2" multiple="multiple">
  <option parent_id=3 my_id=6>Milk Chocolate</option>
  <option parent_id=5 my_id =7>Sprinkled Cookie</option>
  <option parent_id=5 my_id =8>Iced Cookie</option>
</select>

<select id="layer3" multiple="multiple">
  <option parent_id=7 my_id=10 >Dark Sprinked Cookie</option>
  <option parent_id=7 my_id=11 > White Sprinkled Cookie</option>
  <option parent_id=8 my_id=12> White Iced Cookie </option>
</select>
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); //tells me the layer i think
    nextlayerstuff = //get the next layer somehow 
    options = $(nextstuff).filter(not sure what to do here).html()
    //somehow display the new select options for the next layer
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting scenario.  Couple of pointers: you'll need to cache all the values first, which you will want to add or remove accordingly.  You should probably associate parent and child selects (as opposed to just relying on relating parent and child options). It also probably wouldn't be a bad idea to move those ids to data attributes rather than custom attributes.  I've put together a demo that might work for your purposes.  The code is more or less fully documented.

```js
$("select").each(function(){
    // cache all options
    $(this).data('options', $('option', this));
}).on('change', function(e){
    var current = this, selected = [];
    
    // find all selected for the current select and
    // store them in a local variable
    $('option:selected', current).each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).data('id'));
    });
    
    // find all selects that depend on this one.
    $("select").filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('depends-on') === current.id;
    }).each(function(){
        // search our cached options and filter them
        // by the selected option(s).  Store them in
        // a local variable.
        var children = $(this).data('options').filter(function(){
            return selected.indexOf($(this).data('parent')) > -1;
        });
        
        // empty and repopulate the select with the
        // filtered results. Also, trigger the next
        // select so the effect cascades.
        $(this).empty().append(children).trigger('change');
    });
}).trigger('change'); // trigger change so it filters
                      // on page load.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="layer1" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-id="3">Chocolate</option>
  <option data-id="5">Cookie</option>
</select>

<select id="layer2" data-depends-on="layer1" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-parent="3" data-id="6">Milk Chocolate</option>
  <option data-parent="5" data-id="7">Sprinkled Cookie</option>
  <option data-parent="5" data-id="8">Iced Cookie</option>
</select>

<select id="layer3" data-depends-on="layer2" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-parent="7" data-id="10">Dark Sprinked Cookie</option>
  <option data-parent="7" data-id="11"> White Sprinkled Cookie</option>
  <option data-parent="8" data-id="12"> White Iced Cookie </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a follow-up if I have further questions.

Comment: So do you know how I can also dynamically resize the select list. The box by default is small, but I want it to be big when it has a lot of elements, and small when there are not a lot.

Comment: @user3916997 I suppose you can.  It's inadvisable in my opinion, but you can count the children and set the height as a product of that and some factor. http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/om60o6s9/

Comment: Hi thanks for your proposal. I have a question, why the dependent selects always have as auto selected the last option? How I can change it to have the first option on the last select? Regards.

Comment: @Aker666 Unfortunately, I can't reproduce what you are describing.  Does this happen on a particular browser/operating system?

Comment: @Joseph Hi, I'm using Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit). For Jquery I have the 3.4.1 version. Regards.